# bootstrap 4 navbar in a container must have same width

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am novice. I am using bootstrap-4 for making a website. In which there must be a text scrolling in top and after that menu along with logo and name.

I am using two container for the same. 1st for Text scrolling in top and 2nd for menu bar. In 2nd container I am using navbar. But Navbar is not getting same width as its parent container.
I wish both container must have same width along with nav-bar

My Codes:

```
<header>
    <!-- top header for scrolling text marque -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div  style="background-color: black; border-color: orange;  width: 100%; height: 2rem" >
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- for menu -->
    <div class="container" style="border: 1px; border-color:red;border-style: double;height: 4rem;">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md" style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 128);border-style: double;border-color: red;">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<header>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Row for scrolling text -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: black; border-color: orange; height: 2rem">
                <!-- Add your scrolling text content here -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Row for menu -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 px-0" style="border: 1px; border-color: red; border-style: double; height: 4rem;">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 128); border-style: double; border-color: red;">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/users/8149710/haseeb-hassy
The answer is correct and I have also tried this because the same design makes many ways to make it.

Answer (score 1):

Both the `containers` have the same width. The only catch here is that you do not have a `div` with `col` `class`. If you add a `div` with `col-md-12` inside the `row`, it will match the width of the second `container`, like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div style="background-color: black; border-color: orange;  width: 100%; height: 2rem"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The other solution you can try is to add a `p-0` class with the second `container`, like:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <!-- top header for scrolling text marque -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div style="background-color: black; border-color: orange;  width: 100%; height: 2rem">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- for menu -->
  <div class="container p-0" style="border: 1px; border-color:red;border-style: double;height: 4rem;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md" style="background-color:rgba(255, 255, 128);border-style: double;border-color: red;">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Nice , Simple but sharp. u have a sharp eye!